# Rank and unrank fibonacci bitsequence with k ones

Tags: arrays, bit-manipulation, permutation, fibonacci, ranking

For positive integers *n* and *k*, let a "*k*-fibonacci-bitsequence of *n*" be a bitsequence with *k* `1` where the `1` on index `i` describe not `Math.pow(2,i)` but `Fibonacci(i)`. These positive integers that add up to *n*, and let the "rank" of a given *k*- fibonnaci-bitsequence of *n* be its position in the sorted list of all of these fibonacci-bitsequences in lexicographic order, starting at 0.

For example, for the *n*umber 39 we have following valid *k*-fibonacci-bitsequences, *k* <=4. The fibonacci numbers behind the fibonacci-bitsequence in this example are following:

`34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1`

`10001000` k = 2 rank = 0

`01101000` k = 3 rank = 0

`10000110` k = 3 rank = 1

`01101100` k = 4 rank = 0

So, I want to be able to do two things:

- Given *n*, *k*, and a *k*-fibonacci-bitsequence of *n*, I want to find the rank of that *k*-fibonacci-bitsequence of *n*.
- Given *n*, *k*, and a rank, I want to find the *k*-fibonacci-bitsequence of *n* with that rank.

Can I do this without having to compute all the *k*-fibonacci-bitsequences of *n* that come before the one of interest?

Comment: I think this question should be asked on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think this can be solved in about O(n^2). (I suppose this is from some programming competition) is that fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preliminaries

For brevity lets say »*k-fbs of n*« instead of »*k-fibonacci-bitsequences of n*«.

## Question

> Can I do this without having to compute all the k-fbs of n that come before the one of interest?

I'm not sure. So far I still have to compute *some* of fbs. However, you might have thought we had to start from 00…0 and count up – this is not the case. We can do it the other way around and start from the highest fbs and work our way down very efficiently.

This is not a complete answer. However, there are some observations that could help you:

## Zeckendorf

In the following pseudo-code we use the data-type `fbs` which is basically an array of bools. We can read and write individual bits using `mySeq[i]` where bit `i` represents the Fibonacci number fib(i). Just as in your question, the bits `myFbs[0]` and `myFbs[1]` do not exist. All bits are initialized to `0` by default. An `fbs` can be used without `[]` to read the represented number (n). The helper function `#(fbs)` returns the number of set bits (k) inside  an fbs. Example for n = 7:

```
  fbs        meaning       representation    helper functions 
1 0 1 0
| | | `— 0·fib(2) = 0·1 ——— myFbs[2] = 0      #(myFbs) == 2 
| | `——— 1·fib(3) = 1·2 ——— myFbs[3] = 1        myFbs  == 7
| `————— 0·fib(4) = 0·3 ——— myFbs[4] = 0
`——————— 1·fib(5) = 1·5 ——— myFbs[5] = 1
```

For any given n we can easily compute the lexicographical maximum (across all k) fbs of n as this fbs happends to be the [Zeckendorf representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) of n.

```
function zeckendorf(int n) returns (fbs z):
1  int i := any (ideally the smallest) number such that fib(start) > n
2  while n-z > 0
3  |  if fib(i) < n
4  |  |  z[i] := 1
5  |  i := i - 1
```

`zeckendorf(n)` is unique and the only fbs of n with k=`#(zeckendorf(n))`. Therefore `zeckendorf(n)` has rank=0. Also, there exists no k'-fbs of n with k'<`#(zeckendorf(n))`.

## Transformation

Any k-fbs of n can be transformed into a (k+1)-fbs of n by replacing the bit sequence `100` by `011` anywhere inside the fbs. This works because fib(i)=fib(i-1)+fib(i-2).
If our input k-fbs of n has rank=0 and we replace the right-most `100` then our resulting (k+1)-fbs of n also has rank=0. If we replace the second-right-most `100` our resulting (k+1)-fbs has rank=1 and so on.

---

You should be able answer both of your questions using repeated transformations starting at `zeckendorf(n)`.  For the first question it might even be sufficient to only look at the k-stable transformations `011…100`→`100…011` and `100…011`→`011…100` of the given fbs (think about what these transformations do to the rank).